# how can i check a method in raw php, like oop method_exists()

Tags: php

How to use method_exists() without any object or method_exists() alternative way. I have tried:

`method_exists($methodName);`

but its looking for an object. But in general php, there haven't any class .

Comment: A method belongs to a class. It makes no sense to check whether a method exists without the class. A 'method without a class' is a function - are you looking for `function_exists()`?

Comment: I just want the alternate way of method_exists() . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function `bool function_exists ( string $function_name )`
Checks the list of defined functions, both built-in (internal) and user-defined, for `$function_name`. [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)